# Access Antlib Resources From Within Apache Ant Macros

Tags: ant, jar

Is it possible to access resources from within Apache Ant macros defined in an Antlib?

For instance, within my `antlib.xml`, I have a macro that performs some XSLT. Ideally I would like the XSLT file to be packaged in the same JAR as the `antlib.xml`, but I have no idea how to specify the location of the XSLT.

Here is the (simplified) code:

```
<antlib xmlns:tibant="antlib:org.windyroad.tibant">
    <macrodef name="configure-ear">
        <attribute name="xml" />
        <attribute name="out" />
        <sequential>
            <xslt in="@{xml}"
                  out="@{out}"
                  style="...what to put here...">
            </xslt>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
</antlib>
```

The problem is that whatever I put in the `style` attribute is relative to the `basedir` for the project using the antlib and I can't find any way to specify a path relative to the antlib.xml.

Any ideas?

I can ship the XSLT as a separate file, but then I would need to give users some way to specify the location of the XSLT, which is not ideal (e.g. setting a `tibant.home` property). I could also use `echoxml` to write out the XSLT to a temp file, but IMO that's a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `style` attribute, try a nested `<style>` element, which will allow you to specify a [`javaresource`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#javaresource) as the style sheet. You can then put the stylesheet next to your antlib.xml in the jar, and it will be available on the classpath.

```
<xslt in="@{xml}"
    out="@{out}">
    <style>
        <javaresource name="your/package/structure/style.xslt" />
    </style>
</xslt>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get it working, but so far it can't find the xslt unless I explicitly specify the classpath. I'll let you know how I go.

Comment: @Tom Oh the joy of classloading! It looks like `javaresource` is using the core ant classloader by default when in an antlib, rather than the classloader of the antlib itself, which is what I'd have thought was the correct thing. It might even be worth reporting as a bug.

Comment: @Tom A couple of potential workarounds: put the jar in one of the ant lib dirs or use the `-lib` option for ant and rely on ant automatically finding the antlib from the antlib uri namespace declarations (this is what I was doing which is why it seemed to work for me). Then everthing uses the core classloader. Alternatively use the `loaderRef` attribute in the `taskdef` and `javaresource`. You'll have to make sure you use the same string in both, but you won't have to specify the classpath in the `javaresource` in the antlib.

Comment: Maybe also setting the `parentFirst` attribute to `javaresource` (as introduced by Ant 1.8.0) to `false` is worth a try here?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would look at is to load XSL from the classloader as a resource. You should be able to accomplish this with LoadResource task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html). The next I would look at options that XSLT task gives you for the specifying style. It doesn't look like it has any ability to take literal contents of XSLT. You can work around this by writing out the XSLT content to a temporary file and then giving the path to the temp file to the XSLT task.

So...

1. Load XSLT text from the classloader.
2. Acquire a temporary file using Tempfile task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tempfile.html).
3. Write out XSLT text to the temp file using Echo task.
4. Invoke XSLT with reference to the temp file.