# Using Ant's xslt task in a Gradle plugin and make it find a resource

Tags: java, xslt, ant, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm currently working on a Gradle plugin, and that plugin's JAR contains an XSL file that I'd like to use in Ant's `xslt` task as invoked by Gradle:

```
ant.xslt(in: reports.xml.destination,
         out: new File(reports.xml.destination.parent, basename + '.html')) {
    style {
         // From https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/checkstyle/checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl.
        javaresource(name: 'checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl')
    }
}
```

However, although I've included the `checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl` into almost every directory in the plugin JAR, I'm still getting

```
Caused by: : stylesheet checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl doesn't exist.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.handleError(XSLTProcess.java:1413)
```

So I guess either the `classpath` or the `loaderRef` or both is wrong. After reading though [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343441/gradle-add-a-resource-in-plugin-jar) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671816/gradle-plugin-copy-file-from-plugin-jar) to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159858/access-antlib-resources-from-within-apache-ant-macros) I've tried several combinations but they all yield the same error.

What do I need to specify in order to make the Gradle plugin discover the resource embedded into its JAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it wasn't working out of the box was that I missed that the `ant.xslt` call was wrapped in an `antBuilder.withClasspath(getCheckstyleClasspath()).execute` closure further up which explicitly changed the classpath. So the easiest solution is to simply move `ant.xslt` out of that closure.

If that's applicable in your case, another solutions is to load the XSL file to a variable in Groovy code and passing that as a string to Ant:

```
def xsl = Checkstyle.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl')
// ...
style {
   string(value: xsl.text)
}
```